# Html5 video slider with advanced functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been asked by a client to replicate the functionality of the full page video slider on this page

[Facebook Paper](https://www.facebook.com/paper)

The pertinent functionality being each slide being a video that is split into smaller sections that can effectively be scrolled through like individual slides themselves and when the last section of the video is reached pushing the next arrow will move the slider to the start of the next video.

My question is can this be done with no Javascript supporting browsers including ie9 but not earlier?  The client has requested html5/css3 only but I am not sure that is possible.  If it is possible can you post some examples and if it isn't what is the minimum (not in lines of code but pieces of functionality) amount of javascript / jquery that would be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is can this be done with no Javascript supporting browsers including ie9 but not earlier?

**highly not possible.**
The only option you could leverage with CSS is :hover

This can be done easily on javascript.
There are plenty of libraries out there.

I guess client ;) doesnt know what they are talking about when they say HTML5 and javascript

HTML5 is a fancy word which includes advanced concepts which heavily depends on Javascript

Comment: That is how I interpret html5 but I asked them specifically were they trying to do this with no javascript and they said yes so I just wanted to confirm it was not possible before telling them it wasn't.  I am more of a back-end person unfortunately so not as confident with html css and javascript

Comment: understandable. just tell them it cannot be done without javascript :) All the best